# Track Profile Views by Other Profiles

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of users, each with a unique id, and I would like to keep track of which users profile each user views:

For instance if User 56 views the profile of User 104, what's the best/recommended way of storing that in MySQL?

I don't want to count the views, I want to know who views who.

Is a toxi solution best for this? It seems to me that if I'm adding a new row into a table for each new view, that table is going to get pretty big, pretty quickly?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you would like to store just user id of visiting profile you can store by coma separated id in one row you just need to append user id in existing string by coma

for example if profile user id is 56 then other profile_visitor_id may be like 23,42,56,23

so table will be like

```
id, user_id, profile_visitor_id
```

i think this is good way to manage big data in small way.

Comment: That's what I was thinking would be most efficient although I'm not very sure how to add a new id to a single field (profile_visitor_id) separated by a comma, or quite how to read it out.

Comment: when u read it from db if your are using php you can use explode in implode function